# Android How to get all points between two given points?

Tags: android, coordinates, points

I need your help,

how can I get all points (x,y) of a line between two screen coordinates ( start(x,y) / end(x,y) ) in an ArrayList?

Comment: Well you could use Bresnham's line Algorithm to find the points in between.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bresnham's Algorithm was the keyword. :)

Answer (score 0):

use mid point formula. Let Start(x1,y1) and End(x2,y2) are two point then you can get midpoint((x1+x2)/2,(y1,y2)/2) the midpoint b/w start and end use this formula untill you get all the points b/w the start and End.

Hope this will hope.